# C++ - does removing compile time branches remove branching during runtime?

Tags: c++, branch, c++20, template-meta-programming, sfinae

Apologies if any of the terminology is wrong here. What I'm trying to understand is - techniques like template metaprogramming and SFINAE/concepts in C++20 can both compute and remove branches at compile-time. What I can't seem to find an answer for is, does that remain branchless at runtime and/or is the act of finding which function to call based on the overload/specialisation cases faster than an if-else block?

The application I'm thinking about is for automated trading. Let's say a new message arrives from the exchange and it's a "buy" order. One way to deal with that would be a simple if-else statement that checks if it's a buy order and runs the corresponding function to process a buy order message. Conversely, my understanding so far of an alternate solution is that multiple template function overloads could be used to decide which function is called, where the chosen function is the one whose template arguments/requirements are best matched or fully satisfied by the incoming type/class.

Pseudo code below.

Option 1 - branched if statement:

```
if (order.side == "buy") { /*handle buy message*/ }
else { /*handle sell message*/ }
```

Option 2 - function overloads

```
template<class Order>
//some code (SFINAE/concepts/requires) that means this function will only be chosen if the class Order
//contains a member variable "buy" e.g. Order::buy is present or Order::buy = true;
void process_order() { /*handle buy message*/ }

template<class Order>
//some code (SFINAE/concepts/requires) that means this function will only be chosen if the class Order
//contains a member variable "sell" e.g. Order::sell is present or Order::sell = true;
void process_order() { /*handle sell message*/ }
```

What I'm wondering is, during run time, option 1 would always result in a branch. Option 2 is branchless but intuitively feels like some overhead is incurred during run time due to having to still search the multiple function overloads and finding the best fit each time, because buy and sell orders arrive randomly. So my question is - does this overhead actually exist or there is a neat trick being utilised/something different happens? If it does exist, is it still faster than a branch and if so, why - given that some logic must still be used to search for the applicable function? Is it that option 2 is faster/branchless during run time because the compiler can hardwire the path that will be taken based on the class that arises so when that class is presented to the program, it knows exactly which set of instructions to load? Any insight would be appreciated :)

Comment: Option 2 doesn't work in the first place. Overload resolution and template deduction are purely compile-time concepts. They can in no way be affected by runtime values. In the generated code there is always only one function call to the chosen overload.

Comment: If you have to determine the type at runtime, you will always have a branch/jump. Overload resolution happens at compile time.

Comment: "given that some logic must still be used to search for the applicable function?" right. Either you must branch at runtime or not, there is no "magic" (well, branch prediction is kinda magic but thats on the cpu level)

Comment: Templates, SFINAE and conepts are compile time concepts. However, that doesn't mean that they can magically turn runtime branches into compile time branches. Rather those are the tecniques you can use when you can already make the decision at compile time.

Answer (score 1):

Decide what you want.

Reading your comments in Option 2

```
//some code (SFINAE/concepts/requires) that means this function will only be chosen if the class Order
//contains a member variable "buy" e.g. Order::buy is present or Order::buy = true;
```

The point is "`Order::buy is present or Order::buy = true`".

Are completely different conditions

"`Order::buy` is present" is a condition that is known compile time, so you can write something as (caution: code not tested)

```
template <typename Order>
auto process_order () -> decltype(decltype(Order::buy), void())
 { /*handle buy message*/ }

template <typename Order>
auto process_order () -> decltype(decltype(Order::sell), void())
 { /*handle sell message*/ }
```

and the branching is made one time for all, compile-time.

The condition "`Order::buy == true`" (or maybe `o.buy == true`, where `o` is an object of type `Order`) can be decided compile time only if the `buy` value is compile-time know, so if is a `constexpr` value. Otherwise, if is known only run-time, Option 2 is unavailable.